# Can the 'you don't have a [class] badge yet' message be synced to whatever badge you're tracking?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, badges, badge-progress, activity

I have a feature request to make.

Right now, my Profile tab shows the following on Meta:
[image]

Per my interpretation, what this is telling me is: *You don't have a gold badge- if you want to get a gold badge, then write a high-scoring answer- this is a good way for you to get a gold badge.*

However, let's say I've gone to the Activity tab and chosen to track the *Fanatic* badge:

[image]

What I'm saying is: *I have the option to choose which badge to track. The badge I'd like to earn is the Fanatic one.*

**In my opinion, these two should be synced- if I don't have a gold badge, and I'm choosing to track a gold badge, then the little message I receive in the badges box on my profile should indicate so.** In my example, the 'Write an answer that..." text should say something along the lines of "You don't have a gold badge yet. Visit the site for each day for 100 consecutive days to earn your first."

The same would be true for Silver badges if I was tracking one and didn't have any yet. (It's really hard not to have a bronze badge on most main sites, but I guess I'm including that too.)

I don't know- to my mind, the two seem like they should be synced, but perhaps there's a reason that they're not.